# Textview está ficando por trás dos outros objetos

Tags: android, android-layout

Na minha aplicação, tenho um textview que está ficando por trás dos outros objetos da tela, queria que ele terminasse onde o Imageview começa na tela.

Esse layout é utilizando e preenchido em um adapter para o ListView.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

  <TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvBoleiro"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="40sp"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="3dp"        
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/ivGols"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_weight=".8"        
    android:ellipsize="end"
    android:focusable="false"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
    android:textSize="25sp" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/ivGols"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/btPagamento"
    android:layout_weight="0.05"
    android:background="@null"
    android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
    android:focusable="false"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_gol" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btPagamento"
    android:layout_width="70dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/tvBoleiro"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:focusable="false"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
    android:layout_weight=".15" />   
</RelativeLayout>
```

[image: Imagem do Problema]

Comment: Uma duvida, você postou o XML inteiro?

Comment: Sim @GuilhermeNascimento

Comment: São dois XML's um com só com o ListView e outro que é esse que postei que faz a linha do listview

Comment: Isso não sei te dizer, mas queria limitar o tamanho do textview para não ficar deste jeito, consegui editar o post com o xml completo.

Comment: Boa tarde, alguma das respostas lhe resolveu o problema? Se sim por favor marque-a como "Correta". Se não diga o que falta. Grato.

Answer (score 1):

Quando você trabalha com `RelativeLayout` você deve levar em consideração a posição relativa dos elementos ao seu redor, por exemplo: a esquerda de (`android:layout_toLeftOf`), abaixo de (`android:layout_below`), etc. Quando você quiser fazer a distribuição dos elementos considerando um peso (`android:layout_weight`) utilize `LinearLayout`, pois senão você não terá o resultado esperado.

No *layout* que você fez, você utilizou ao mesmo tempo no `TextView` as propriedades: `android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"` e `android:layout_alignParentRight="true"`, ou seja, você determinou que seu `TextView` será alinhado a esquerda e a direita, ocupando a largura toda do elemento pai (`RelativeLayout`).

Para que seu `TextView` não seja sobreposto por outros elementos, remova dele a linha `android:layout_alignParentRight="true"`, pode remover também os `android:layout_weight`, eles não farão diferença alguma (nesse caso), seu XML deve ficar assim:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvBoleiro"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="40sp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="3dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/ivGols"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:textSize="25sp" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@id/ivGols"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/btPagamento"
        android:background="@null"
        android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_gol" />

    <Button
        android:id="@id/btPagamento"
        android:layout_width="70dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@id/tvBoleiro"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="false" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Se optar por usar `LinearLayout`, uma alternativa seria:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvBoleiro"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="40sp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="3dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
        android:layout_weight=".65"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:textSize="25sp" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/ivGols"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight=".15"
        android:background="@null"
        android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_gol" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btPagamento"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight=".20"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="false" />

</LinearLayout>
```

> **Nota:** utilizei `android:layout_width="0dp"` para que os elementos sejam distribuídos corretamente de acordo com seus pesos e `android:maxLines="1"` para aparecer os `...` quando e texto for maior que o limite.

**Referências**

[Linear Layout](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/linear.html)
[Relative Layout](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RelativeLayout.html)
[Adicionar reticências no TextView com uma ou múltiplas linhas](https://zarelli.wordpress.com/2013/02/11/android-adicionar-reticencias-no-textview-com-uma-ou-multiplas-linhas/)

Answer (score 0):

Neste caso para prevenir o "overlap" (sobre posição dos itens) será necessário usar `LinearLayout` ao invés de `RelativeLayout`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

  <TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvBoleiro"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="40sp"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="3dp"        
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/ivGols"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_weight=".8"        
    android:ellipsize="end"
    android:focusable="false"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
    android:textSize="25sp" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/ivGols"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/btPagamento"
    android:layout_weight="0.05"
    android:background="@null"
    android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
    android:focusable="false"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_gol" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btPagamento"
    android:layout_width="70dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/tvBoleiro"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:focusable="false"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
    android:layout_weight=".15" />   
</LinearLayout>
```

> Nota: talvez no `<Button>` seja necessário usar `wrap_content` na largura também, assim
>   `<Button ... android:layout_width="wrap_content">`

Answer (score 0):

Dentro do adapter no método getView tem o trecho para adicionar o BadgeView:

```
if (convertView == null) {

        holder = new PresencaViewHolder();

        convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.tela_lista_presenca_linha,
                null);

        // Find the child views.
        holder.tvNomeBoleiro = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.tvBoleiro);
        holder.btPagamento = (Button) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.btPagamento);
        holder.btAddGol = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.ivGols);

        holder.badge = new BadgeView(context, holder.btAddGol);

        convertView.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        // Because we use a ViewHolder, we avoid having to call
        // findViewById().
        holder = (PresencaViewHolder) convertView.getTag();

    }
```

Analisando o código da lib do BadgeView ví que ele usa FrameLayout, então usei o layout que vc postou e coloquei o imageview que recebe a Badge dentro de um FrameLayout e deu certo.

```
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/laGols"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/btPagamento" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/ivGols"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@null"
        android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_gol" />
</FrameLayout>
```